# Is py-fill-paragraph broken in python-mode.el?

Tags: python, emacs

Start Emacs with

```
emacs -q  /tmp/test.py
```

Paste this into the buffer

```
class Class(object):
    """A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line."""
```

Put the point somewhere on the triple-quoted string, then do

```
M-x py-fill-paragraph
```

I get the following error:

```
Marker does not point anywhere
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem... what emacs version do you use?

Comment: @juanleon GNU Emacs 24.2.1 and python-mode.el 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce. What is the value of `py-docstring-style`?

Detected a minor-bug, when checking your example. Report is here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1241147

Comment: The value of `py-docstring-style` is `pep-257-nn`. It's defined in `python-mode.el`.

Comment: @ErnestA emacs -q some-file will load the shipped python-mode, which might be the cause of error. Try the following: make sure, python-mode.el is loaded from your init, start emacs normally, open test.py, "Py" in modeline should appear. Than M-q should fill-paragraph according to py-docstring-style.